# 1 I have no idea what causing the error in my android project. The error "Failed to start several time. Restore it by clearing its history."

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

Ila vasthe am cheyyali telugu lo matladandi okkk

Nenu app ni open cheyyalaka pothunna

1

I have no idea what causing the error in my android project. The error "Failed to start several time. Restore it by clearing its history."

Comment: Can you try running it on a fresh emulator instance and see if that makes any difference? Is there anything useful in the logcat?

Comment: You've tagged this thinktecture-ident-server - how is that related?

Comment: ... and I'm afraid I can't answer in Telugu. This is an English-language site sorry - please can you translate the first few sentences for us?